# Endpoints stopped working with proxy.html error

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

Error I'm getting
Refused to display 'ah/api/static/proxy.html?jsh=m%3B%2F%2">https://appname.appspot.com/*ah/api/static/proxy.html?jsh=m%3B%2F*%2…8s_uMxLg#parent=http%3A%2F%2Fappname.appspot.com&rpctoken=....' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.

Everything worked until yesterday. Started browser this morning to access app and got above message. Getting this on other endpoint apps too. Seems to fail when I access the endpoints to get info from the backend.

Comment: Nate, looks like it. My issue is with Java based back-end. But issue is the same.

Answer (score 1):

End points are indeed down for several of our apps. Certainly an error on google's side. Got to wait.

Worked till we refreshed the browser page today!

Error noted from Chrome's JavaScript Console:

```
GET https://_____.appspot.com/_ah/api/static/proxy.html?jsh=m%3B%2F_%2Fscsâ¦L3eu8s_uMxLg#parent=http%3A%2F%2F_____.appspot.com&rpctoken=689483000 404 (Not Found) cb=gapi.loaded_0:116
Refused to display 'https://_____.appspot.com/_ah/api/static/proxy.html?jsh=m%3B%2F_%2Fscsâ¦L3eu8s_uMxLg#parent=http%3A%2F%2F_____.appspot.com&rpctoken=689483000' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'. about:blank:1
GET https://_____.appspot.com/_ah/api/static/proxy.html?jsh=m%3B%2F_%2Fscsâ¦L3eu8s_uMxLg#parent=http%3A%2F%2F_____.appspot.com&rpctoken=401828000 404 (Not Found) cb=gapi.loaded_0:116
Refused to display 'https://_____.appspot.com/_ah/api/static/proxy.html?jsh=m%3B%2F_%2Fscsâ¦L3eu8s_uMxLg#parent=http%3A%2F%2F_____.appspot.com&rpctoken=401828000' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'. about:blank:1
```

Update (somebody is apparently working on it), the error has changed to:

```
Invalid gadgets.rpc token. 429366340 vs 703741727 cb=gapi.loaded_0:41
c cb=gapi.loaded_0:41
_.Mb._.sa cb=gapi.loaded_0:41
h cb=gapi.loaded_0:59
c cb=gapi.loaded_0:52
Uncaught Error: m`apiproxy0e30dfc60185e9bebed936e8008c20776b338f810.6918280611280352 cb=gapi.loaded_0:71
_.T.Ca.Mm cb=gapi.loaded_0:71
h cb=gapi.loaded_0:59
c
```

Comment: Update: Fixed now. Verified to be working (on few of our apps). However the console still shows a couple of uncaught errors.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Endpoints discovery seems to be failing, but it's on Google's side and not your code.  Star this issue and get updates on its progress:

https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=9167