# Package name error in app engine connected android project after endpoint library generation

Tags: android, eclipse, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

After creating a new app engine connected android project it immediately generates errors in the build path of the generated client libraries. It suddenly happened in my other main project (that project has been working for quite some time) and after failing to solve it I created a new test project which has the same error from the start. I have tried cleaning the project, restarting Eclipse, even re-installing Eclipse... Any ideas?

Regards

See screenshots here:

[image]
<sub>(source: [osmoel.se](http://www.osmoel.se/stackoverflow/packages.jpg))</sub>

And

[image]
<sub>(source: [osmoel.se](http://www.osmoel.se/stackoverflow/errors.jpg))</sub>

Comment: I'm having exactly the same problem.  I've now upgraded to GAE SDK 1.7.7.1, regenerated client libraries, and rebuilt everything, to no avail.   I take it that, for you, the problem just went away?

Comment: Seems like an Eclipse bug to me (I'm on 4.2.2) as the error msg makes no sense (the declared package DOES match the expected package.  When I try the 'quick fix' Eclipse does strange things confirming that it is very confused.

Comment: Haha - Yes. Eclipse was oddly confused. I waited a few days and google seemed to work out the problem. Sorry for the late response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that Google has some issues with Cloudendpoints today after the release of the appengine sdk 1.7.7. There was another problem described here where cloudendpoint users could not see their APIS in the api-explorer (https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/)

- https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=9167
- [Endpoints stopped working with proxy.html error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15967102/endpoints-stopped-working-with-proxy-html-error)

Comment: Thanks! I was hoping it would be something like that =)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the relevant issue:

https://code.google.com/p/google-plugin-for-eclipse/issues/detail?id=117